# Is there a way to make Sonarcloud not showing me a specific code smell error?

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarcloud

There's a specific code smell error in sonarcloud which I don't want it to be shown anymore.
Is there a way to do it through it's config file (sonar-project.properties)? Or maybe through a github action? thanks in advance!

I tried to search anywhere and only got a way to remove the whole code smell analysis - which I don't want. I want a specific error to stop being alerted.